# In Chinese Led torch how does the LED automatically light down when recharging?

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, rectifier, battery-operated, led-driver

I repaired some led rechargeable torches which work under 230 V.
When we plug it to main socket for charging even with the switch on, the LED goes off. What mechanism in these torches to off the LED when it is under recharging?. No transistor is there,  only a rectifier and smoothing capacitor and some resistors are there.[image][image]

Comment: Photo and schematic, please.

Comment: Most likely you are either missing something, such as a COB (blob) or parts you can't see, or there is a mechanical switch in the plug. We have no way of telling from your question.

Comment: I traced the circuit. But no such special mechanism. I replaced the burnt ressistor, so it is now working. I can't understand how the white led off automaticaly(i think to protect it)when pluged in.

Comment: There are at least three resistors on the PCB and only one in your 'schematic'. Also there is only one LED of the two shown. Maybe something else is missing, like on the back of the PCB or under that electrolytic capacitor.

Comment: no. under that nothing.

Comment: I ignored the red indicator led

Answer (score 3):

Here is the circuit schematic. I don't think this particular flashlight has that functionality. The LED stays on regardless of the presence of power at the mains terminals (if the switch is on).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF86Kp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: D5 looks ... vulnerable, on -ve half cycles...

Comment: @user_1818839 Non-ideal but good enough to work for a while I guess. No series resistance to limit surge current through C1 either.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Sphero. It is the same circuit that I have.But still I don't know how does the white led goes off with power in.

Comment: no problem with D5. It is the indicator led. half wave is enough for it.Must there be a resistor series with C1?. I think the internal ressistance of the cell is enough.

Comment: Can some one please tell me how to use schematic designer tool in this site?

Comment: The LED sees negative half cycles and will break down every half cycle with perhaps -70V across it. Series resistor is because if it is powered at the 300V peak input the peak  current can be high enough to damage the capacitor. These are not controversial observations.

Comment: To use the schematic editor/simulator just click the button and play with it. It does not work on phones.